# How to create new row of data in Excel automatically after splitting up data within a cell

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2016

I've this data set that contain 100K+ of records. 
And in 1 row of cell, its contained multiple products code, separated by comma (,). The cell might contained between 1 - 5 products codes separated by comma.

There a Unique Id no. tag to each product codes.
Here is the tricky part:

1. I need to split so each cell only contain 1 items
2. and create a new column below for every product code
3. then populate the new column with data contained in other rows

Meaning to say

```
Row A     | Row B      | Row C   | Row D|
Unique ID | Product ID | Price   | MSRP |
1232      | 123,342,432| $5      | $10  |
```

And I need to transform this record into,

```
Row A     | Row B      | Row C   | Row D|
Unique ID | Product ID | Price   | MSRP |
1232      | 123        | $5      | $10  |
1232      | 342        | $5      | $10  |
1232      | 432        | $5      | $10  |
```

Is there anyway to do it beside, "Text to column" and copy and paste the other data with the records?
I'm totally new to VBA but I'm willing to give it a try.

Comment: *but I'm willing to give it a try* - please show the efforts you've tried and where it's failing. Then we can help you solve them. SO is not a "write code for me" service.

Comment: A hint to start with: Loop through all rows. Use use  [`yourArray = split()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6x627e5f(v=vs.90).aspx) to split them into an array by the delimiter `,`. Get the array size with `x = UBound(yourArray)` and duplicate the actual line x-times. Then write the values from the array into the actual and generated rows.

Comment: @Scott, 
What I'm doing now is manual.
Step 1: Move Column B to the End of the Column
Step 2: Split by Column by delimited ( ,  )
Step 3: Copy Whatever that is split from Column D onward and transport to the last row
Step 4: Drag the Information of Column A - C down

Comment: @Peh, are you doing a VBA?
I'm new to VBA so i'm trying to figure out everything

Answer (score 0):

I made this done by Google Sheets after adding 5 + 2 helper colmuns, just for some fun. It heavily uses `arrayformula()`, `filter()`, `split()`, `join()`, `regexreplace()`, which are not supported naitively or provided as built-in formulas in Excel.

1. First, get 5 `pid`s for each record by `=split(B2, ",")` on `K:K`. It will expand to column `O:O`.
2. Get one line of all records for each `uid`s by `=regexreplace(join("/", arrayformula(if(K2:O2<>"",$A2&","&K2:O2&","&$C2&","&$D2,""))), "/+$" , "")` on `Q:Q`. It joins every column with `,` and each record with `/`.
   (You may use `substitute()`, etc instead of `regexreplace()`.)
3. Now joining `Q2:Q` will give all records. Just one formula `=transpose(split(join("/", filter(Q2:Q, Q2:Q<>"")), "/"))` on `R2`.
4. Now split each record on `R:R` with `,` by one formula `=arrayformula(split(filter(R2:R, R2:R<>""), ","))` on `F2`.

Sample sheet is [here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1xZ1FwsnTHvcTA8a9syss3r5LgE9mP7MB4FB78LK_oqg/) and below is its scrrenshot.
[image]

Another screenshot showing cells with formulas.
[image]

Comment: Thanks @Sangbok Lee,

I tried what you're doing on Excel before and this is okay if im going it across.

What i need is with each New Id created by the split from Cell B, i need to create a new record below and replaced it with all the other information.
Not too sure if you know what i mean

Comment: DV for providing a solution outside the requested application.